# What is difference between the return value of the method named "textFieldShouldReturn(textField:)"?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextviewdelegate

I have doubts when i implement the delegate method `textFieldShouldReturn` of `UITextField`, I don't know what's difference between the return value.

I have tried `return false` and `return true` in it, but I didn't find the difference between them, and my custom delegate methods are all executed, the program seems to work fine.

Here is my code:

```swift
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        let legalInput = tagTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        if !legalInput.isEmpty {
            if isUpdate {
                if tag!.tagName != legalInput {
                    delegate?.didUpdateTagName(tagName: legalInput)
                }
            } else {
                delegate?.didAddTag(tagName: legalInput, themeId: themeId)
            }
        }
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

        // return false
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`YES` if the text field should implement its `default` behavior for the `return button;` otherwise, `NO`.

The text field calls this method whenever the user taps the return button. You can use this method to implement any custom behavior when the button is tapped. For example, if you want to dismiss the keyboard when the user taps the return button, your implementation can call the `resignFirstResponder` method.

You can read it on [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619603-textfieldshouldreturn?language=objc).

If you want to hide the keyboard when the user clicks `return button` then

```
return true
```

otherwise default is `false` , the logic depends on your `UX` of whether you want the keyboard visible all time or not.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Yes I have read Apple doc before, but what's its "default behavior" for the return button, if I want to dismiss the keyboard, I can call the "resignFirstResponder", then "return false", and then it works too. The return value like has no effect. I have tried it:

Comment: func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        return false
    }